# Showing record with a specific ids first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i have to show all users on a page.
But i have an `array` which old some `ids` of a user let say `[1,2,3]`
I want to show all records on a page but those included in the list should be on top.
can it will be done through `ActiveRecord` query or i have to fetch all user first and then put some operation on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, at least with MySQL:

```
User.order("id IN (#{array.join(',')}) DESC")
```

of course, you need to be careful you have full control of your `array` content with this solution. Also, this breaks if `array` is empty, so you have to check for its emptiness, for example:

```
@users = array.any? ? User.order("id IN (#{array.join(',')}) DESC") : User.all
```

The advantage of this approach is you still have `ActiveRecord::Relation` object on the end, on which you can call another AREL methods, like `where`, or apply pagination.

Comment: This got break if array is empty []. can it will be fix in the query?

Comment: @NitinJ probably not, I guess you'd have to check for array emptiness in Ruby.

Comment: Can You see the Jacob Solution and tell me what is the preferable way to do this.

Comment: Yes, I can. With my solution, the result is still `ActiveRecord::Relation`, on which you can call AREL methods, like `where`, or apply pagination.

Comment: can you edit the answer so it will say that user have to take care of array emptiness as it will be helpful for someone who Use this answer and it works with postgresql also

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do two separate queries and merge the results:

```
User.where("id IN (?)", ids) + User.where("id NOT IN (?)", ids)
```

A bit more complicated solution would be to fetch all the users at once and then sort them using a custom sorting method, which would prefer the numbers from your array.

Comment: this is a good answer, and hopefully the number of `ids` don't ever crank up to the '000s